# SQL Server: compare names ignoring non-alpha

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a database table with a text column "title".
New rows are inserted all the time, and every time I would like to check for potential duplicates on this column.

I define duplicate by "having the same sequence of alpha characters". So, for example, if I already have the string "Lisa's Nights":

- "LISASNIGHTS" is duplicate, because case doesn't matter, spaces don't
  matter, apostrophe doesn't matter
- "Lisa's Night" is not duplicate because the final 's' is missing.

Of course I could store an altered version of the title and search there. But is there any other solution?

Answer (score 3):

You can do it on the fly without storing the stripped down name, but that would mean recalculating the strings (e.g. Lisa's Nights, Lisa's Night, LISASNIGHTS) each time a new entry should to be checked against an existing string.

On the other hand, if your table also has a column for the STRIPPEDDOWNNAME, you can leverage SQL Server's constraints.  Create a `UNIQUE CONSTRAINT` (or a `UNIQUE INDEX`) on the STRIPPEDDOWNNAME column.  Then you will calculate the stripped down name only once, when you insert it into the table.  With the `UNIQUE CONSTRAINT` the SQL Server will immediately let you know if an inserted string is a duplicate.

You can then capture the error and respond as appropriate to your application.

I encourage you to let the SQL Server manage the duplicate check whenever possible.

Comment: +1 STRIPPEDDOWNNAME should be a persisted computed column. SQLCLR can be used to do all the char handling (remove spaces etc)